# How to create your own data type for an attribute

Tags: c#, types

I have an Invoice that has particular fields to complete by the user and save it in the database. This particular fields have a name and a value. The value could be text, date, int or another type in the future, I have to do it extensible.

```
Example:
Invoice 1, ParticularField 1, "Hello world"
Invoice 2, ParticularField 1, "Bye bye"
Invoice 3, ParticularField 2, 1234
Invoice 4, ParticularField 2, 5678
```

How can i get the value of the "ParticularField" from the class "ParticularFieldValue" to complete this value.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: 'How can i get the value of the "ParticularField" from the class "ParticularFieldValue" **to complete this value**'. What do you mean by "complete this value"? Wouldn't creating a "ParticularField" class containing a string type **Name** and object type **Value** suffice?

Comment: Yes, but if another Invoice want to change the value of the same ParticularField, the database will update it.

Comment: I don't understand the model. What is the `ParticularFieldValue` with `Type Value` property between Invoice and ParticularField? How is it related to the `Type` class between the field and the concrete types?

Comment: ParticularFieldValue is the class that has an Invoice and a ParticularValue and determines the value with the type asosciate to the ParticularValue.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your data as a pure object and than cast it to Type.

```
class FieldValue
{
    private object data;
    private Type type;

    public object Data
    {
        get { return data; }

        set
        {
            data = value;
            type = value.GetType();
        }
    }

    public Type Type
    {
        get { return type; }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do you cast it to the correct type, for example int without knowing what it is?

Comment: I think you have to write a switch(FieldValue.Type) to determine the type and do appropriate action for each type.

Comment: Ok, but then the caller must do the switch. You can't have this functionality inside this class. I'd prefer gemerics instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but here goes nothing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name1 = "ParticularField 1";
        string name2 = "ParticularField 2";
        string name3 = "ParticularField 3";

        string value1 = "this is a string";
        int value2 = 12345;
        DateTime value3 = DateTime.Today;

        ParticularField pf1 = new ParticularField(name1, value1, value1.GetType());
        ParticularField pf2 = new ParticularField(name2, value2, value2.GetType());
        ParticularField pf3 = new ParticularField(name3, value3, value3.GetType());

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + pf1.GetName());
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + pf1.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + pf1.ValueType);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + pf2.GetName());
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + pf2.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + pf2.ValueType);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + pf3.GetName());
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + pf3.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + pf3.ValueType);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
public class ParticularField
{
    string Name;
    public object Value { get; }
    public Type ValueType { get; }
    public string GetName() { return Name; }
    public ParticularField (string name, object value, Type type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        ValueType = type;
    }
}
```